# Windows Batch: ": was unexpected at this time" error in For command

Tags: android, batch-file, adb, aapt

I am attempting to check multiple devices for installed APKs using adb and aapt.
Currently I have brought through the list of APKs on my PC on a per device basis. I am now attempting to match those PC APKs to the Package name on the device, however, the line `FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%D IN ('adb shell "pm list packages" | !CUT! -d' -f2' ":") DO (`appears to be causing the error `: was unexpected at this time`.

Please see the short code:

```
::Global
@echo off

set AAPT=tools\aapt.exe
set GREP=tools\grep.exe
set CUT=tools\cut.exe

:: Install Gold Build applications
cls
@echo.
@echo ------------------------ CHECK APPLICATIONS INSTALLED --------------------------

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%A IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%B
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%A
        echo.
        echo Device !SERIAL! Connected
        echo.
        for /f "delims=" %%B in ('dir /b ^"APKs\*.apk^"') do (
            SET APK=%%B
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%C in ('%AAPT% d badging APKs\!APK! ^| !GREP! "package: name=" ^| !CUT! -d' -f2') do (
                set package=%%C
                if "!package!" == "" set package=Unknown (
                echo !package!
                    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%D IN ('adb shell "pm list packages" | !CUT! -d' -f2' ":") DO (
                    SET DEVPACKAGE=%%D
                    echo !DEVPACKAGE!
                        if "!DEVPACKAGE!" == "!package!" (
                        echo Application !package! is installed on device !SERIAL!
                            else (
                            echo Application !package! is not installed on device !SERIAL!
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
@echo.
@echo.
@pause
```

Are you able to identify the issue? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to escape the pipe. Just like you did when piping to grep.

Comment: Believe I told you this in a previous question.  You do not need to set your FOR variables to Environmental variables to use them.  You are just creating more overhead.  Also, you would not even need to use delayed expansion if you would just use the FOR variable instead.

Comment: Not sure why you are using GREP and CUT.  You can easily do those commands with the commands built-in to Windows already.  You can use FIND and FINDSTR instead of GREP and the FOR /F command will allow you to use the colon as a delimiter and let you chose which TOKEN (field) you want.

Comment: My apologies! I see that now. In my defence I've mainly self taught batch over the past week. Thank you though